# Ember exclude a mixin from specific route

Tags: ember.js

I have a mixin for authorization checking which is included in application route so that all other routes get access to the mixin without explicitly importing it. However, I want to  exclude  my login route from inheriting it. How can I achieve that? One workaround is to import the mixin in all routes individually but that's error prone and don't want to resort to it unless I am sure that there is no way out.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you make the mixin route-hierarchy-aware, so that you'd only have to mix it in the parent routes? ember-simple-auth does it that way.

Comment: Can you share some pseudo code to help understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible! All routes are nested inside the application route.

Better to have another parent route for all authenticated routes (e.g. `/main`) and you can extend the mixin here.

Other routes like login, register, forgot password,.. etc will be out of that authenticated route.

Comment: So in that case, do I just import the mixin in main and all it's children will inherit the mixin. Will try this.

Comment: Technically children will not inherit the mixin. But as they are nested under main route, the authentication check you added to the main route by extending the mixin will happen before you load the children routes.

Comment: So yes, just extend the mixin only in the main route.

Comment: One downside to this approach is that the urls will show up as main/* like main/profile, main/dowork and so on. How to overcome this?

Comment: we actually do that at www.hyperlogs.com and you can see it in action at even intercom.  you will notice that the app routes are all nested under /a so you can alias your main route to "a"... so login would be /login but say user/edit would be inside main at the url would be /a/user/edit - I don't think there is a workaround for that.  my route definition for main is `  this.route('main', {resetNamespace:true, path:'/a'}, function(){`